# Making many-to-many relationships with different price for different customer

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I have three models `Product`, `Buyer` and `Offer`.
Any buyer can inquire about any kind of `Product` but for each customer I might offer a different price.

The net price of a product is already given by the supplier.

I wrote the code below and suddenly realized I can only select products for an offersheet but cannot give a different price every time for each product and for each customer with this code.

It would be nice if anyone could give me some suggestions.
Thanks.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    net_price = models.NumericField(...)

class Buyer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class Offer(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_created=True, auto_now_add=True)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(Buyer, default='',)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='offer',)
```

Comment: Have you considered maybe creating another model called `CustomPrice` that's linked to a `Product`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as following:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class Buyer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class Offer(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_created=True, auto_now_add=True)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(Buyer)

class OfferUnit(models.Model):
    offer = models.ForeignKey(Offer)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    net_price = models.IntegerField()
```

`OfferUnit` is like one row in your bill(invoice) so you can specify different price for different buyers.